# Create group notifications firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to create a group notification on firebase function everytime which a new user creates his account, but i can't understand where I have to put this Http post request which is written on [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group)

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=API_KEY
project_id:SENDER_ID

{
   "operation": "create",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to combine two samples from the Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation. First is [Notify users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens), which shows how to send a FCM message to users upon changes to the database. But since you instead want to send a message when the user registers, you'll need to combine it with [Send a welcome email when a user completes signup](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users), which shows how to trigger when a user registers.

If you're having problems making these work, please share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your reply. I've understood that i have to use triggers but I still don't know where do I have to write my http post request.. on index.js ?

Comment: Yes, the code would go into index.js and be triggered by an account creation. But I get the impression that you might benefit from first reading the [Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), taking [its codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#0) and potentially the [Cloud Functions module in the Udacity course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud0352/lessons/9d2e8938-1714-420b-8421-03757d7d51a5/concepts/27745d96-8b24-4470-84cd-856a2cfa7716).

Answer (score 1):

The answers given in the comments are largely non-answers and I think the official documentation is extremely weak regarding this (very necessary) topic. Considering the fact that many users have multiple devices I'm a bit surprised that FCM/Cloud Function integration has not yet addressed group messaging within the FCM API within Cloud Functions (you can currently send-to, but not manage device groups). This gave me a severe headache for a day (I am not a fan of JS/TS), so I'm going to cover the general concepts anyone else will need in case they stumble upon this same question. Which is a good question when you run into some of the *gotchas* I mention below.

To use the legacy API you'll need to use an HTTP client package which you can [install from npm](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs). I recommend using [request-promise-native (henceforth I'll refer to as 'rpn')](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) for a few reasons. First and foremost, if you intend on saving the information you receive in the response on firestore (which... you likely will) then you'll want to implement promises across the board since firestore gives you promises and you'll need that to make sure your function operates as expected. The standard request package uses strictly callbacks - this is what gave me most of my headaches as I originally tried nesting the callbacks that ended with a promise after writing to firestore. You could make those callbacks in the standard request package into promises, but why when you could just use rpn? Second, I choose rpn over axios because I read on another SO thread that axios doesn't like to work on cloud functions so I avoided it all together. There are other packages available but rpn was simple enough to use. The rpn package also worked great using the latest NodeJS 8.0 framework's async/await keywords which is what I'm using in the example below.

Now... how about some code? This is written in TS but should be relatively the same for JS. First you create the object containing all the options you want for the request and then wait for the response. It's pretty simple and straightforward once you know you really need to use an HTTP package with promises.

```
const postOptions = {
      uri: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification",
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {  
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization" : fcmServerKey,
        "project_id" : senderID
      },
      json: {
        "operation": 'create',
        "notification_key_name": userID,
        "registration_ids": [token]
        }
    }

    const postResponse = await request(postOptions)
    const theKey : String = postResponse['notification_key'];
//now do something with the key
```

Comment: I was keeping the tokens in Firestone but this makes way more sense